# JAVA how to summarise the score of soccer team from the text file?

Tags: java

My assignment is I have to manage a soccer league.There is a soccer league (text file) that I have to import into the program.Each line of the imported file displays the outcome of a single game:the name of two teams together with the scores like

Peter 4 Tiger 3

Sky   2 Peter  0

Tiger 1 Sky 2

I have to write the program to read this text file and displays the output of team records like

Team      Wins   Losses

Peter      1       1

Tiger      0       2

Sky        2       0

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

I have tried to connect the whole  knowledge that I have ever read from the textbook but it's not work.I just know that how to import the text file into java program. But don't know how to use the integer/data from that file into calculated/string progression  .I cannot really realise the hint  that can guide me to the solution.Anyone can help me please?
I have just learned java by myself for a few months.

BIG THANKS.

Comment: Please show your code where are you stuck? We'll be properly able to catch your problem!

Comment: Make a class `Team` with properties `name`, `wins`, and `losses`. Keep a `Map<String, Team>` (key is team name) and update the `wins` and `losses` fields as you go through the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    private static class Results {

        private int wins = 0;
        private int looses = 0;

        public void addWin() {
            wins++;
        }

        public void addlost() {
            looses++;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {

            return wins + " " + looses;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "FileLocation.txt"));
        String line;

        Map<String, Results> teamResults = new HashMap<>();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = line.split(" ");
            Results team1 = teamResults.getOrDefault(data[0], new Results());
            Results team2 = teamResults.getOrDefault(data[2], new Results());
            if (Integer.valueOf(data[1]) > Integer.valueOf(data[3]))
                {team1.addWin();
                team2.addlost();}
            else
                {team1.addlost();
                team2.addWin();}
            teamResults.put(data[0], team1);
            teamResults.put(data[2], team2);

        }

        for (String string : teamResults.keySet()) {
            Results teamres = teamResults.get(string);
            System.out.println(string+ " " +teamres);
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Sky 2 0
Peter 1 1
Tiger 0 2
```

Comment: I'm using fancy "getOrDefault" from java 8 (I believe). If running previous version of JDK - replace it with usual get and null checking/ creating new object.